# Combinations in long format by group

Tags: r, combinations, parent, long-integer, siblings

So I have a dataset of parents and their children of the following form

```
Children_id   Parent_id
10            1
11            1
12            1
13            2
14            2
```

What I want is a dataset of each child's siblings in long format, i.e.,

```
id   sibling_id
10   11
10   12
11   10
11   12
12   10
12   11
13   14
14   13
```

What's the best way to achieve this, preferably using datatable?

**Example data:**

`df <- data.frame("Children_id" = c(10,11,12,13,14), "Parent_id" = c(1,1,1,2,2))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The graph experts out there will probably have better solutions, but here is a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[df,on=.(Parent_id), allow.cartesian=T] %>% 
  .[Children_id!=i.Children_id, .(id = i.Children_id, sibling=Children_id)]
```

Output:

```
      id sibling
   <num>   <num>
1:    10      11
2:    10      12
3:    11      10
4:    11      12
5:    12      10
6:    12      11
7:    13      14
8:    14      13
```

Answer (score 3):

In `base R`, we can use `expand.grid` after `split`ting

```
out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df$Children_id, df$Parent_id), \(x) 
     subset(expand.grid(x, x), Var1 != Var2)[2:1]))
row.names(out) <- NULL
colnames(out) <- c("id", "sibling_id")
```

-output

```
> out
  id sibling_id
1 10         11
2 10         12
3 11         10
4 11         12
5 12         10
6 12         11
7 13         14
8 14         13
```

---

Or using `data.table` with `CJ`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, CJ(id = Children_id, sibling_id = Children_id),
    Parent_id][id != sibling_id, .(id, sibling_id)]
      id sibling_id
   <num>      <num>
1:    10         11
2:    10         12
3:    11         10
4:    11         12
5:    12         10
6:    12         11
7:    13         14
8:    14         13
```

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` solution with `inner_join`:

```r
library(dplyr)
inner_join(df, df, by = "Parent_id") %>% 
  select(id = Children_id.x, siblings = Children_id.y) %>% 
  filter(id != siblings)

  id siblings
1 10       11
2 10       12
3 11       10
4 11       12
5 12       10
6 12       11
7 13       14
8 14       13
```

---

or another strategy:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Parent_id) %>% 
  mutate(siblings = list(unique(Children_id))) %>% 
  unnest(siblings) %>% 
  filter(Children_id != siblings)
```